# How to pass system environment variables to app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible? Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs8
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PORT: 8080
  API_KEY: ${API_KEY}
```

`${API_KEY}` is like a placeholder.

When I run `API_KEY=xdfj212c gcloud app deploy app.yaml` command, I want to pass `API_KEY=xdfj212c` to `app.yaml` and replace the placeholder with 
`xdfj212c`.

Expect result:

```
runtime: nodejs8
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PORT: 8080
  API_KEY: xdfj212c
```

Or, After I run

1. `export API_KEY=xdfj212c`
2. `gcloud app deploy`

I want the same behavior.

Is this make sense for google app engine deployment workflow?

Comment: This question is a duplicate and has been fully answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620747/10801700

Answer (score 4):

In `app.yaml` you can [include](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#includes) another YAML config

```yaml
includes:
- extra_env_vars.yaml
```

that you can create on the fly while inserting the [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#environment_variables)

```sh
# Unix-like OS
export DB_PASSWORD=your_password
export DB_HOST=your_host
echo -e "env_variables:\n    DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD\n    DB_HOST: $DB_HOST" > extra_env_vars.yaml

# Windows
set DB_PASSWORD=your_password
set DB_HOST=your_host
(echo env_variables: & echo.    DB_PASSWORD: %DB_PASSWORD% & echo.    DB_HOST: %DB_HOST%) > extra_env_vars.yaml
```

The resulting `extra_env_vars.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
env_variables: 
    DB_PASSWORD: your_password 
    DB_HOST: your_host
```

Finally, ignore `extra_env_vars.yaml` in your version control system.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use `sed`:

```sh
$ sed -i 's/${API_KEY}/xdfj212c/g' app.yaml && gcloud app deploy
```

The 'bad' thing is that this stores the key back, but you can always append a new `sed` command to replace the key again with the placeholder, or use your VCS mechanism to just reset the change the file.

Another option is saving your `app.yaml` file as something like `app_template.yaml` and do this for your deployments:

```sh
$ sed 's/${API_KEY}/xdfj212c/g' app_template.yaml | tee app.yaml; gcloud app deploy
```

This will do the replacement in a new file, `app.yaml`, and then do the deployment.